# Notification server to client, post a res.render(), after a time-intensive function has ended

Tags: node.js

When a user follows a route in my application, a time consuming function begins executing.

Can i render a page on that route in the beginning of the request, then when the time-intensive function ends, send something to that page, a message, to notify the user that the time-intensive work is done?

And then, when the page that the user is on, receives the message, it displays a hidden div with a link?

Are Flash messages able to do that?

Comment: i believe it is possible with web sockets

Comment: You mean socket.io?

Comment: yes, if you are  using nodejs

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebSocket or event better [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

Take a look at [sse-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-express)

**edit** I've created a [simple working example](https://github.com/Teneff/sse-example)

Comment: I saw that it uses  res.sse() as a middleware. Can i still run this, after i have performed my res.render() for that route?

Comment: @user1584421 The idea is that you'll have to run client-side JS which will subscribe to the `SSE` and instead of checking periodically with `XHR` the server will send an event once the action is completed. In other words you will need a separate endpoint to which you'll subscribe

Comment: I am trying to understand how this will work client side. The docs are really poor. Do i put the client code inside a <script> tag? Then what's up with this line? let eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:80/updates'); What if my route is not a GET one, but a POST one. Do you have any link of a working example of this code?

Comment: This solution does not work. I tried some code but i do my res.render(), then i try to send some message from the server with res.sse('connected', {
        welcomeMsg: 'Hello world!'
     });  I get this error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Comment: Like i said in my original question, i want to render a page first, then when the function ends, the server should send a message to the page already rendered.

Comment: @user1584421 try with a different endpoint for the SSE request

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is my code: 
app.post('/pst', sseExpress, function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.convo;
  res.render('error.ejs');
  res.sse('connected', {
        welcomeMsg: 'Hello world!'
     });
});

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. But as i glanced over the code, you don't do any res.renders(). So it it possible to res.render() a template and then do a res.sse() in the same route?

Comment: @user1584421 you can send 2 different HTTP responses based on the `req.headers.accept`

Comment: I dont understand what you meant with your comment. Also, in your example, the job.js file is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179847/discussion-between-teneff-and-user1584421).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a div in your page which will make a AJAX request to you time consuming API once the API sends the response your div will get populated with the data sent by your API.

So, The rendering process can happen in following way:

1. You render a page as soon as the request has made
2. The div on the page makes an AJAX request to time consuming API
3. Once API in step 2 successfully respond the div gets populated with the data

Comment: Thanks! I will try this, since the other answer didn't work. Since i have not worked with AJAX before... What do i have to read in order to implement this, both for the client and the server incoming/outgoing AJAX calls?